# Average with sum of values equal to number of values

Tags: average

I have a list of numbers.
Each number can be any amount above 0 but under 1 million.
There are 1 million numbers.

The numbers add up to 1 million.

Is it possible to calculate an average (Mean)?
Normally calculating the mean does not work as 1 million / 1 million = 1 of course.

This is a bit of a random question but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us call your numbers $(X_i)_{1\leq i \leq 10^6}$. The mean is defined as 
$$ \mu = \frac{1}{10^6} \sum_{i=1}^{10^6} X_i=1$$
so the mean is $1$. You can either define it as the mean of this specific series or the probabilistic mean in both cases it will be $1$.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much for your response. I will mark this as the answer when I can and use a different average.

Comment: The only case where it could be different from $1$ is if the $X_i$ are correlated to have a sum equal to $10^6$ but that taken alone they have a different distribution. But in that case you need to specify what variables you are talking about.